# org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'fastPassId' cannot be found on object of type 'byte[]'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am following video series from here: https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=5133b583-6d21-4f49-b069-95f5ae7a60d8 and last section is not quite working well for me. The only thing I changed is I'm using latest version of **Spring Boot 2.7.0**.

Source Code: **https://github.com/javaHelper/Java-Microservices-with-Spring-Cloud-Coordinating-Services/tree/main/8.setting-up-and-using-partitions**

Error:

```
2022-06-09 19:24:53.805 ERROR 1084 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'null'; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'fastPassId' cannot be found on object of type 'byte[]' - maybe not public or not valid?, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[57], headers={scst_partition=2, id=69ffc57c-eb16-8565-22d7-3729bb8ab48a, contentType=application/json, target-protocol=amqp, timestamp=1654782893792}]] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'fastPassId' cannot be found on object of type 'byte[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338) ~[spring-expression-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.PartitionHandler.extractKey(PartitionHandler.java:140) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.PartitionHandler.determinePartition(PartitionHandler.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DefaultPartitioningInterceptor.preSend(DefaultPartitioningInterceptor.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:469) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:309) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:235) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:150) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.example.FastPassController.getFastPassCustomerDetails(FastPassController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

The code which is giving trouble is line-35

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Controller
public class FastPassController {

    @Autowired
    StreamBridge streamBridge;


    @RequestMapping(path="/customerdetails")
    public String getFastPassCustomerDetails(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "800") String fastpassid, Model m) {

        WebClient client = WebClient.create();

        FastPassCustomer customer = client.get()
            .uri("http://localhost:8091/fastpass?fastpassid=" + fastpassid)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(FastPassCustomer.class)
            .block();
        
        System.out.println("fastpassid: " + fastpassid);
        m.addAttribute("customer", customer);

        System.out.println("Customer : "+ customer);
        
        //send message to stream endpoint first
        streamBridge.send("generatetollcharge-out-0", new FastPassToll(fastpassid, "1000", 1.05f)); //line-35

        //return view name
        return "console";

    }
    
}
```

Almost the code is same

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what's on the video, since i need to sign up but based on the stack trace it appears you are trying to use SpEL on the payload which exists in its raw format `byte[]`. That is about as much as I can say since I don't have a view into the application.
Consider creating a small sample in Github so we can clone and take a look to avoid the guessing game.

Comment: Here is the my complete source code: https://github.com/javaHelper/Java-Microservices-with-Spring-Cloud-Coordinating-Services/tree/main/8.setting-up-and-using-partitions, please guide and help me to share knowledge & POC around Cloud Function

Comment: Oleg - Would you like to take a look at the code and respond?

Comment: You have provided a multi-module application which. I don't know how to run it to reproduce the issue. Please provide a small independent and isolated sample that reproduces the issue as a single SpringBoot application that anyone can clone/build/run and observe the issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You might solve your issue by changing your Spring Cloud Version in your `fastpass-ui/pom.xml` from what you currently have

```
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
```

to

```
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0-RC1</spring-cloud.version>
```

If you get a dependency conflict error in your IDE, I suggest you delete contents of .m2 repository.